# Is the wmd-button-bar image of SO pagedown editor free to use in open-source projects?

Tags: discussion, pagedown

I was planning to use pagedown for a project.

The image available on [StackExchange/pagedown](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown) github page is

[image]

The image that I am referring to is the one that is currently used on StackOverflow.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Img/unifiedmeta/wmd-buttons.svg?v=bafd44c6da2c

[image: the image used on meta]

I searched a lot and I was not able to find any info on this.

Is the use of this image allowed? If so, what are the terms?

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/master/LICENSE.txt and https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/master/package.json, wherein the license field says "MIT".

Comment: @HereticMonkey As mentioned in my question, the licencing information you are referring to is for the image that I have embedded in the question. I am asking about the image currently being used in the SE sites, the link to which is given in the question.

Comment: I've edited the question to inline the image so it's clearer that you're talking about a different image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NO**

I was able to reach the company via the contact page.

> Until the design team opts to release our images as part of the open
>   source content, you should assume that the icons currently used on our
>   sites are part of our site design and subject to our copyright policy.
>   Thus, they are not available under any license.

**Update**

I was not able to find a better image for the button bar. What I did was to add *font-awesome* icons as background images to the buttons. Even though not as good as having the SO icons, this satisfies my requirement.

[image]